# Flutter custom background does not display after updating to null safety

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, dart-null-safety

I recently upgraded my flutter project to null safety and my page stopped showing the body of the scaffold. I think the problem is with the Mediaquery even tho I am not sure about it.

I am using a custom background to design my page, the background:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
class Background extends StatelessWidget {
final Widget? child;

const Background({
Key? key,
@required this.child,
}) : super(key: key);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

return Container(
  width: size.width,
  height: size.height,
  child: Stack(
    alignment: Alignment.center,
    children: <Widget>[
      Positioned(
        top: 0,
        right: 0,
        left: 0,
        child: Image.asset("assets/top1.png", width: size.width),
      ),
      Positioned(
        top: 0,
        right: 0,
        child: Image.asset("assets/top2.png", width: size.width),
      ),
      Positioned(
        top: 30,
        //left: 20,
        right: -60,
        child: Image.asset("assets/logo.png", width: size.width * 0.60),
      ),
      Positioned(
        bottom: 0,
        right: 0,
        child: Image.asset("assets/bottom1.png", width: size.width),
      ),
      Positioned(
        bottom: 0,
        right: 0,
        child: Image.asset("assets/bottom2.png", width: size.width),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
}
}
```

and this is how my login page is set:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final bloc = Provider.of(context);
Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

return Scaffold(
  body: Background(
    child: SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          _title(),
          SizedBox(height: size.height * 0.03),
          _email(bloc),
          SizedBox(height: size.height * 0.03),
          _password(bloc),
          Container(
            alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
            margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 40, vertical: 10),
            child: TextButton(
                onPressed: () async {
                  Navigator.push<Widget>(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (BuildContext context) => ResetScreen()),
                  );
                },
                child: Text(
                  "Passwort vergessen?",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 12,
                    color: Color(0XFF2661FA),
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                )),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: size.height * 0.05),
          _boton(size, context, bloc),
          Container(
            alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
            margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 40, vertical: 10),
            child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () => {
                Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, "register"),
              },
              child: Text(
                "Sie haben noch kein Konto? Registrieren",
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 12,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    color: Color(0xFF2661FA)),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
}
```

I can see the custom background but I am not able to see the actual widget inside the column:

[image]

I experienced this issue after migrating to null safety and I really think it has something to do with it, because if I take the background out and I use the SingleChildScrollView as the main widget for the body, everything in the column appears again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@required` has been changed to `required` in null safe dart. You can also remove the "?" from `Background.child` if it is required as it will never be null.

```
class Background extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;

  const Background({
    Key? key,
    required this.child,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    return Container(
      width: size.width,
      height: size.height,
      child: Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          // add the child somewhere in the build function
          child,
          Positioned(
            top: 0,
            right: 0,
            left: 0,
            child: Image.asset("assets/top1.png", width: size.width),
          ),
          Positioned(
            top: 0,
            right: 0,
            child: Image.asset("assets/top2.png", width: size.width),
          ),
          Positioned(
            top: 30,
            //left: 20,
            right: -60,
            child: Image.asset("assets/logo.png", width: size.width * 0.60),
         ),
          Positioned(
            bottom: 0,
            right: 0,
            child: Image.asset("assets/bottom1.png", width: size.width),
          ),
          Positioned(
            bottom: 0,
            right: 0,
            child: Image.asset("assets/bottom2.png", width: size.width),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for taking the time to look at the code, I just did the changes but it did not solve the issue

Comment: No problem :) Is `child` being used in your `Background` widget? I can't see it anywhere in the `Background`?

Comment: no, child is being used in the login page. in this case it is the SingleChildScrollView

Comment: You seam to be passing the `SingleChildScrollView` to the `Background` widget as a child. But then in the `Background` widget you are not using it (or at least I can't see where). I will update my answer with an example of using the child.

Comment: you are right I solved it by adding the child before closing the stack. thanks a lot for the time and spotting that mistake